# How to validate reactive form using Bootstrap?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

My simplified code:

```
<div class="tab " *ngIf="booking">
 <div class="confirmation-email card" *ngIf="showConfirmationEmailForm" id="confirmationEmail">
   <div class="card-header">
     <span>Some text</span>
   </div>
   <div class="confirmation-email-content">
    <form [formGroup]="emailForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">
           Description
        </label>
        <input type="email"
            id="email"
            formControlName="email"
            class="form-control"
            required minlength="4"
            placeholder="name@example.com">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Invalid email!</div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="onResendConfirmation()">Resend Confirmation</button>
     </form>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know If there is too much parenthesis or if I'm missing any class like form-group. I would like the input to be validated like here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/#server-side
however in the link there is already added is-valid or is-invalid class, which normally is automatically added by Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle server-side validation, you need to handle client-side validation first.
You can use the following code:

```html
<div class="tab " *ngIf="booking">
  <div class="confirmation-email card" *ngIf="showConfirmationEmailForm" id="confirmationEmail">
    <div class="card-header">
      <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="confirmation-email-content">
      <form [formGroup]="emailForm" (ngSubmit)="onResendConfirmation(emailForm.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">
            Description
          </label>
          <input type="email" id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" required minlength>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding (ngSubmit)="onResendConfirmation()" doesn't seem to work